# Unable to find sling project wizard in eclipse

Tags: sling

I am new to sling and trying to create a sling project in eclipse but i am unable to find wizard and also i am unable to create a sling server.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed AEM IDE tool into eclipse which included sling within it which was not allowing to include sling in the list of wizards.

I had to open a fresh eclipse window which had no AEM IDE tool installed in it and then install sling IDE tool which will able you to create sling project and also allow you to install sling server.

Comment: If this is the right answer to your question please accept it.